# Place text input and anchor tag on same line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am designing some page in which I have created one row with two text input and one anchor tag, but why anchor tag will not sit together on same line with text input.

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wb8vpbc3/13/

```
<div class="row floating-labels">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Phone number <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control input-sm" data-original-title="Enter Company Official website" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-validation-required-message="This field is required" id="txtUsername" maxlength="35" name="phoneNumber" required="" title="" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Extension <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control input-sm" data-original-title="Enter Company Official website" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-validation-required-message="This field is required" id="txtUsername" maxlength="35" name="Extension number" required="" title="" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <a class="btn btn-info" data-target="#addPhoneModal" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)">+</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give `col-5` to phone number, `col-3` to the anchor tag

Comment: no that's not I have tried this

Comment: That is due to `<h5>` tag. Add some margin top to anchor tag.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered making use of the `.input-group` class, which would allow you to combine your modal trigger (which as a side note; should probably be a `<button>`) with the `input`?

Below is an example of that layout in Bootstrap 4; it may not match your design entirely as I've scrapped all of the customization off and presented it using just the Bootstrap 4 structure.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card company mx-2 my-2">
  <p class="text-right mx-2 my-1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-info"><small>skip</small></a></p>

  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title text-info text-center">Tell us more about your Company</h4>

    <form>
     
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-6">
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone number <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
        <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="txtUsername" class="form-control input-sm" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required" maxlength="35" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="Enter Company Official website">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-6">
        <label for="Extension number">Extension <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="Extension number" id="txtUsername" class="form-control input-sm" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required" maxlength="35" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="Enter Company Official website">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info" alt="default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addPhoneModal">+</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
    
    </form>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's breaking because of the padding-right property in default `col-12` as well as `col-sm-4` class.
And it will eventually break if you reduce the screen size.

Better to overwrite the class with following CSS:

```
.col-12,
.col-sm-4 {
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Here is the working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wb8vpbc3/15/)